# data table (View) not refreshing after jQuery Ajax call in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm facing below issue while refreshing data that has been POSTed using Ajax in MVC. The POST is successfully being executed, but the data on the VIEW does not get refreshed with the new data. When I debug, the values from the Ajax POST are successfully being passed to my controller. When the controller returns the view model return View(objLMT);, my VIEW is not refreshing the new data. How do I get the new data to show in my VIEW?

AJAX

```
function getAllUserRoleCompany() {
    debugger

    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllUserRoleCompany", "UserRoleCompany")';

    var Organisation = $("#Organisation").val();

    if (Organisation == "All") {
        Organisation = "";
    }
    else {
        Organisation = Organisation;
    }

    var RoleName = $("#RoleName").val();

    if (RoleName == "All") {
        RoleName = "";
    }
    else {
        RoleName = RoleName;
    }

    var i = 0;
    if ($("#UserName").find("option:selected").length >= 0) {
        var len = $("#UserName").find("option:selected").length;
    }
    else {
        len = 0;
    }


    var UserName = "";



    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if ($("#UserName").find("option:selected")[i].text != "All") {
            if (i == 0) {
                UserName = "',";
            }

            if (i < len - 1) {
                UserName += $("#UserName").find("option:selected")[i].text + ",";
                UserName = UserName.substring(0, UserName.indexOf("-")) + ",";
            }
            else {
                UserName += $("#UserName").find("option:selected")[i].text + ",'";
                UserName = UserName.substring(0, UserName.indexOf("-")) + ",'";
            }
        }
    }

    if (UserName == "All") {
        UserName = ""
    }
    else {
        UserName = UserName;
    }

    var UserStatus = $("#UserStatus").val();

    if (UserStatus == "All") {
        UserStatus = "";
    }
    else {
        UserStatus = UserStatus;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { Organisation: Organisation, RoleName: RoleName, UserName: UserName, UserStatus: UserStatus },

        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#dataTables-example").bind("");
            //$("#dataTables-example").bind();
            //location.reload(true);

        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
```

Below is the view code on the same page

```
<div class="row">
@Html.Partial("pv_UserRoleCompany", Model)
```

[image]

Controller

```
  public ActionResult GetAllUserRoleCompany(String Organisation, String RoleName, String UserName, int UserStatus)
    {
        LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
        LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

        string usrNameWithDomain = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        //string userID = "261213";  // Environment.UserName;
        string userID = "100728";

        ViewBag.UserRoleId = objLMTDAL.GetRoleID(userID);
        objLMT.TypeList = objLMTDAL.UserRoleCompany_GetAll(Organisation, RoleName, userID, ViewBag.UserRoleId, UserName, UserStatus);

       // return Json(objLMT, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return PartialView("pv_UserRoleCompany", objLMT);
    }
```

With above code My while SEARCHING or UPDATING view my table/Grid is not refreshing.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning a partial view from an AJAX call you have to use jQuery to "refresh" the data.

In your js code you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { Organisation: Organisation, RoleName: RoleName, UserName: UserName, 
            UserStatus: UserStatus },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        //$("#dataTables-example").bind("");
        //$("#dataTables-example").bind();
        //location.reload(true);
        $("#dataTables-example").html(data);
    },
    error: function (reponse) {
        alert("error : " + reponse);
    }
});
```

This will replace the existing HTML with the one from the partial view result in your controller.

Comment: Please Find My comments above

Answer (score 0):

@Mihail I have tried using the above solution. It Works I mean it refreshes my view but It's not loading my view perfectly as expected.

View Before (Expected)
[image]

View After using $("#dataTables-example").html(data);
[image]

Comment: Try specifying widths for the table columns in the `thead`.

Comment: @MihailStancescu Yes, I have Applied the width to the thead part. The problem the result view is it is creating one more di element "User Role Managment" after refreshing.

Comment: Hmmm , my guess is that you have an extra object in the `Model.TypeList`, please check the query results.

Comment: It seems your top level "User Role Management" is getting inserted again, clear the placeholder of the main element first and then write the response as mentioned by @MihailStancescu

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you
Call this function as per your call:

```
function getAllUserRoleCompany(parameters) {
    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/UserRoleCompany/GetAllUserRoleCompany',
        data: { Organisation: Organisation, RoleName: RoleName, UserName: UserName, UserStatus: UserStatus },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#").empty().html(data);

        }
    });

}
```